# Stop Scrolling after a certain scroll in scrollview - Titanium

Tags: titanium, scrollview

I am just developing a Titanium App. I want to disable scrolling of a scrollView after some scrolling . In other words I want the scroll to stop at a certain position of my screen. Suppose I want the below scrollView to stop scrolling after it scroll a height of 200px. How can I do this?

```
var containerScroll = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    backgroundColor : 'transparent',
    opacity : 0.0,  
    showVerticalScrollIndicator : true,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears this would be your answer, but it is iOS specific.  Set the 'scrollingEnabled : false' property.  I wasn't able to find an Android version for you.

```
var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
  views:[new generateVerifyView(),new generateUserView(),new generateAddrView()],
  showPagingControl : false,
  scrollingEnabled : false
});
```

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122741/disable-scrolling-in-a-scrollableview

Answer (score 0):

YOu try about

```
scrollview.contentOffset="200";
```

this is working for me ...